# How do I delete files from all subdirectories but not from hidden directories?

Tags: perl, bash, shell, scripting

I want to delete only files from all subdirectories, but not to delete any files from hidden directories starting with `.`. Example:

```
Directory
├── file1
├── file2
├── .hidden directory
│   ├── log
│   └── txt
└── subdir
    ├── file a
    └── file b
```

How to delete `file1`, `file2`, `file a` and `file b`? That should not delete `log` and `txt`.

Answer (score 3):

This is a 1-liner with `find`

```
find . -path "*/.*" -prune -o \( -type f -exec rm {} + \)
```

#### Example

```
$ find .
.
./.hidden
./.hidden/log
./.hidden/txt
./file1
./file2
./subdir
./subdir/filea
./subdir/fileb

$ find . -path "*/.*" -prune -o \( -type f -exec rm {} + \)

$ find .
.
./.hidden
./.hidden/log
./.hidden/txt
./subdir
```

Answer (score 1):

Here a small sub doing the job:

```
sub clean_dir
{
    my $dir = shift;
    require File::Spec;

    if ($dir && -d $dir && opendir(DIR, $dir))
    {
        my @all = grep { -d (File::Spec->join($dir, $_) && m/^\./) } readdir(DIR);
        @all    = map { File::Spec->join($dir, $_) } @all;
        closedir(DIR);
        foreach my $f (grep { -f $_ } @all) {
            unlink($f);
        }
        foreach my $d (grep { -d $_ } @all) {
            clean_dir($d);
        }
    }
}
```

`File::Spec` is used to properly handle the element separating character, that is "/", "\" or whatever else is used on your system.

Answer (score 1):

One way:

**Tree of files before running the script:**

```
ls -1aR Directory/
```

Output:

```
Directory/:
.
..
file1
file2
.hidden
subdir

Directory/.hidden:
.
..
log
txt

Directory/subdir:
.
..
filea
fileb
```

Content of `script.pl`:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use File::Find;

die qq[Usage: perl $0 <directory>\n] unless @ARGV == 1;

die qq[Argument must be a directory\n] unless -d $ARGV[0];

find( \&wanted, $ARGV[0] );

sub wanted {
        if ( -d && m/\A\.[^.]/ ) {
                $File::Find::prune = 1;
                return;
        }

        if ( -f ) {
                unlink $_ or warn qq[Cannot delete $File::Find::name\n];
        }
}
```

Run the script:

```
perl script.pl Directory
```

**Tree of files after running the script**:

```
Directory/:
.
..
.hidden
subdir

Directory/.hidden:
.
..
log
txt

Directory/subdir:
.
..
```